# Does Mongo know what tuples are?

Tags: python, mongodb, tuples, pymongo

I'm storing lists of tuples into a MongoDB database using `PyMongo`. For some reason, when I view the data in the mongo shell, the tuples are represented by square brackets.

In addition, when I extract the data from the database and check its `type()`, python tells me it's a list.

Is it possible to store a tuple in a mongo database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Mongo actually uses a [BSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/bson-types/)-like structure so it does not support tuples. That is why PyMongo converts them for you to lists. Of course, you can convert them back to tuples when you load them from Mongo.
As you can see from the link above, many types are supported, the most common ones being:

- Double
- String
- Object
- Array
- Binary data
- Boolean
- Date
- Null
- Regular Expression